# pointer to array from serperate .cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Trying to point to an array from a separate .cpp but getting NULL values from 
my array.

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    storage exp;
    cout << exp.pointer[0];
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

storage.h

```
class storage
{
    public:
    storage();
    int* pointer = experience;
    int storage::experience[10];
    ~storage();
};
```

storage.cpp

```
storage::storage()
{
}
int experience[10] = { 100, 200, 400, 600, 1000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000;
storage::~storage()
{
}
```

It's a rpg thingy. I need to return array values but I can't do that and I can't create the array from scratch because it's handmade values. It has to go somewhere. I don't want to put it in the main(done so before in a separate code) because i'm trying to learn how to do this with pointers but I am doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Weird things? This is just sample code from Visual Studio's Class wizard. Made a quick concept of what my issue was. I want to show one value from the array from storage.cpp to the main.cpp.  It would be nice to be able to get the array from another class so that debugging the program later on will be less of a hassle. It would be appreciated to know why this isn't giving me the value I want.

Comment: Also, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers, so there's really no need to have a separate pointer variable for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think storing pointers and having each object contain its own would be the best way to do this. If all objects of the storage class share the same values for the `experience[10]` array, then you should declare it as a `static int`, not an `int`, in the declaration of the `storage` class in `storage.h`. Don't specify that it's inside the class `storage`;  you're declaring the variable inside the class declaration, so that isn't needed.

```
class storage
{
    //other variables
    static int experience[10];
};
```

Then in `storage.cpp`, put:

```
int storage::experience[10] = { 100, 200, 400, 600, 1000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000 };
```

(don't forget the end brace before the semicolon!)

Then all objects in the storage class "share" the int array; there's only one instance of that member which any objects can access to read.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Trying to point to an array from a separate .cpp but getting NULL values from my array

First of all, the line

```
int storage::experience[10];
```

is invalid C++ code. The compiler should report that as an error. What you probably meant to have in storage.h is:

```
extern int experience[10];

class storage
{
    public:
    storage();
    int* pointer = experience;
    ~storage();
};
```

Comment: Thanks this is one solution but I don't want it to be global.  Is there a way to get a pointer that points to an array?

Comment: @quincy9000, I don't fully understand your question. `storage.pointer` points to an array.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I guess I more mean so that it doesn't have to be global and that it doesn't point to null. Cadie Scassera got it to work the way I want. But still stuck on multi-dimensional arrays with pointers.